# Move all except one item to a single row with scrollbar in flexbox

Tags: css

I have some layout like this:

```css
.foo {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.bar {
  padding: 1rem 6rem;
  text-align: center;
  background: #A0E7E5;
}

.active {
  background: #B4F8C8;
  order: 99;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
  <div class="bar">1</div>
  <div class="bar">2</div>
  <div class="bar active">3</div>
  <div class="bar">4</div>
  <div class="bar">5</div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to prevent wrapping of the blue divs and instead show a scrollbar for the first row (preferably without layout modification)? Basically any of the items (`.bar`) can be marked as `.active` and I want to show the active one on a separate row at end.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS Grid to achieve a similar effect. Make `foo` a grid with 2 rows and give it some width. Then add `overflow` property to it to create scrollbar.
By default place all `bar` div on the first row and all the `.bar.active` to the second row.

```css
.foo {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.bar {
  padding: 1rem 6rem;
  text-align: center;
  background: #A0E7E5;
}

.foo {
  width: 500px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}

.bar {
  grid-row: 1;
}

.active {
  grid-row: 2;
  background: #B4F8C8;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="foo">
    <div class="bar">1</div>
    <div class="bar">2</div>
    <div class="bar ">3</div>
    <div class="bar">4</div>
    <div class="bar active">5</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.bar {
  padding: 1rem 6rem;
  text-align: center;
  background: #a0e7e5;
  flex: auto;
}
```

You can add `flex:auto` on to the bar class which kinda solves the problem and there will be no need of scrollbar.